# How to distinguish variables in inception model?

Tags: tensorflow

I read the code of Inception model, but I am confused about the Variable sharing.

In [line 116](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L116) and line 117:

```
        # mixed: 35 x 35 x 256.
    with tf.variable_scope('mixed_35x35x256a'):
      with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
        branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
      with tf.variable_scope('branch5x5'):
        branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(net, 48, [1, 1])        //line 116
        branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(branch5x5, 64, [5, 5])  //line 117
```

the weight Variables for those two layers have the **same** `variable_scope` and **same** name `weights`? The only possible case is that the Variables are shared, but obviously, those two Variables have different shapes (1x1 vs 5x5) and are unsharable? Anyone please explain about it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ops.conv2d()` is a TensorFlow Slim convenience function for creating a 2-D Convolution layer, including weights and bias variables. Although the function *supports* variable sharing, it defaults to no sharing—instead creating a new variable scope on each call—and you must pass the [optional `scope` and `reuse` arguments](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3be9ece9574d7bac07704e43705741d9af1de1e6/inception/inception/slim/ops.py#L207) to enable sharing explicitly. Therefore the two calls to `ops.conv2d()` create separate weights and biases variables.